# cannot ssh into Elastic MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, elastic-map-reduce

I'm using `elastic-mapreduce` to spun new clusters from the command line. After reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-mapr-launch-m7.html) tutorial, I have:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive \
--instance-type m1.xlarge\
--num-instances 5 \
--supported-product mapr \
--name m7 \
--args "--edition,m7"
```

a new cluster with 6 nodes(1 master + 5 slaves) will be created. So I try to `ssh` into the master:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow j-3FLVMX9CYE5L6 --ssh
```

and I get `Permission denied (publickey)`
The `permissions.json` file is in the `elastic_mapreduce` home, and also the path to the `my_key.pem` file.
Also, by doing:

```
ssh -i my_key.pem hadoop@masternode
```

I also get `Permission denied (publickey)`. my_key.pem has been given `400` permissions. I honestly don't know what can I try next ... any clues?

When I go to the `EC2` console, and I click in `Connect`, I get the following error message:

```
Instance is not associated with a key pair.
This instance is not associated with a Key Pair. Without a Key Pair you will need to log into this instance using a valid username and password combination.
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your EMR cluster make sure you enable a key pair. On EMR console you can see it like below:

[image: EMR]

Answer (score 0):

To augment [Rico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2989261/rico)'s comment, above; I would add that you can pull down the key on the command line when you --create the cluster:  for your example:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive \
--instance-type m1.xlarge\
--num-instances 5 \
--supported-product mapr \
--name m7 \
--args "--edition,m7"
--key-pair hadoopKey
```

Were "hadoopKey" is the **name** given to a keypair created *via* the AWS console.

When you SSH in, you are providing this key as "identity"--this means that the host server must have the private key (PEM file in this case).  This action parameter (or Rico's example above) will push that key file onto the (and ONLY the) Master EC2 server.

N.B., if you want to SSH from the Master to one of the Worker boxen, you need to push the same PEM file to the master and then proceed as usual from there.

*E.g.*,

```
you@devbox:$ scp -i hadoopKey.pem hadoopKey.pem hadoop@ec2-the-master-server:
you@devbox:$ssh -i hadoopKey.pem hadoop@ec2-the-master-server:
<figure out the IP of a worker from w/in that Master
hadoop@ec2-the-master-server:$ ssh -i ~/hadoopKey.pem hadoop@the.worker.box.ip
```

Hope that helps.